# How to make a wget and mysql bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, console, wget

I want to make a bash script that will get a bunch of urls from a mysql table and pass all the urls one by one to the wget --spider , and update the mysql with the response code from wget: "HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK" 
I really don't know where to start from .. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

DBNAME=DB_NAME
USER=USER
PASS=PASS
HOST=localhost
STATEMENT="select name from environment;"

COUNTER=$(mysql $DBNAME -h $HOST -u$USER -p$PASS  -e "$STATEMENT")

for entry in $COUNTER; do
  echo wget $entry
done
```

Here is the output

```
 ./mql.sh 
wget name
wget Prod
wget uat
```